# prometheus unit test for Summary

Tags: unit-testing, prometheus

Im trying to write a unit test for 'Summary' but not sure what variables I need to check?

```
from prometheus_client import Counter, Summary
import unittest
import time
from prometheus_client import REGISTRY

my_summary = Summary('my_summary', 'A useful help string.')


def my_function():
    time.sleep(1)
    my_summary.observe(5)



class TestMyFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_metric_incremented(self):
       print 'here'
       before =  REGISTRY.get_sample_value('my_summary')
       print 'summary before == ', before       
       my_function()       
       after =  REGISTRY.get_sample_value('my_summary')
       print 'summary after == ', after
       self.assertEqual(0, after - before)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is my code I observe the function 5 seconds. Not sure if this is the right approach..Any test example would be great.

I tried following this blog - https://www.robustperception.io/how-to-unit-test-prometheus-instrumentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time series you want are `my_summary_count` and `my_summary_sum`.